# Chrome extension to alert, in a condition of a value

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, plugins, alert, servicenow

I started to write a script for that, the actual purpose of it would be, to have a more noticeable alert, for agents in ServiceNow.

The manifest.json is:

```
 {
    "name": "ChatAlert script",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "ChatAlert!",
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["chatalert.js"],
      "persistent": false
    },
    "manifest_version": 2
  }
```

I found a div with the value, and i want to trigger the pop up windows, if there are more then 0 chats, waiting in the queu and the browser detects it, the chatalert.js is:

```
var tmp = document.getElementsByClassName("sn-connect-queue-list-count sn-badge default ng-binding")[0];
setinterval (function() if ( tmp > 0) {
  window.alert (tmp.innerHTML are waiting. Please pick it up.);  
}); }, 30000);
```

Still it doesnt seem to work, Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a couple errors in your JS, I would change it to something more like:

```
var tmp = document.getElementsByClassName("sn-connect-queue-list-count sn-badge default ng-binding")[0];
window.setInterval( ()=>{ alertUser(tmp.innerHTML) } , 30000);

function alertUser( numCalls ) {
  if (numCalls > 0) window.alert( `${numCalls} are waiting. Please pick it up.` );
}
```

(edit) Or you could do this:

```
window.setInterval( function() {if (tmp.innerHTML > 0) { window.alert( tmp.innerHTML + ' are waiting. Please pick it up.' ); } }, 30000);
```

https://codepen.io/wyndhammer/pen/dyYNXOW?editors=1010

Comment: It works, but it repedeatly pops up, so he agents are not able to pick up the chat, because, it blocks the page. Any idea how to alert without blocking the webpage?

Comment: Yes, so window.setInterval actually has a return value that you can cancel. But I’m guessing you actually want to use “window.setTimeout” because that only fires once

Comment: Another option is to create a custom alert that acts more like a “toast” or “snack bar”, you can find examples of that online

Comment: Thank your for your reply. Right after setinterval did not work, I tried to use the settimeout, but the looping was still an issue. I read something about the cleartimeout as well, but not clear, if that would be help on it, with delayed/triggered checkings, as it would stop the action for all. Is there any cance I can make this run in JS, every half minute once , without looping? I'd prefer this more than the toast or snack bar, as it's more noticeable(though if there is no other soution in JS, I'll might need to accept that solution, but would first still try the alert.).